# Gsheet timing out because of script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've just started trying to write some scripts, so thought I'd start off easy. Unfortunately the sheet has been timing out and I've been getting this error message:

*"Aw, Snap!": Chrome is having problems loading a webpage you're trying to see.*

I wanted to align all cells to the left, change all font to Verdana and set all font sizes to 10.

Here is a view-only test sheet, just random data to simulate the amount of data I could have in a real sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ph1uF8asyKODjoB6td752-TPndc9MndyVJUmz9HKeQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code I cannibalised/adapted/wrote, sorry if it's in the wrong format/layout:

```
function onEdit()   {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var cell = ss.getRange('A1:BZ5000');
  cell.setFontSize('10');
  cell.setFontFamily('Verdana');
  cell.setHorizontalAlignment('left');  
}
```

I'm fairly sure it's the range/number of cells which is causing the problem, but I need the script to affect every single cell on all the sheets.

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to remove the numbers from the Range, because you force the Spreadsheet to create this range even if this is not necessary.
(for example your example data have just 1000 lines, but your script forces to create 4000 additional lines multiply by the amount of columns which is huge :D)

just replace

```
var cell = ss.getRange('A1:BZ5000');
```

with

```
var cell = ss.getRange('A:BZ');
```

that should be enough

so your code would be:

```
function onEdit()   {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var cell = ss.getRange('A:BZ');
  cell.setFontSize('10');
  cell.setFontFamily('Verdana');
  cell.setHorizontalAlignment('left');  
}
```

Hope this helps!

**PS.:**
Just another note, from my personal experience.. i wouldn't create such an huge event onEdit.. i would suggest to create onEdit just an active Cell changer, so whenever someone writes stuff into a cell, it will be automatically changed according your needs :)

for example

```
function onEdit()   {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var editCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  editCell.setFontSize('10');
  editCell.setFontFamily('Verdana');
  editCell.setHorizontalAlignment('left');  
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for for your help, you answered my question and then improved the idea, so full marks! Didn't think of making the single cell change rather than the whole sheet, but makes much more sense. Thanks again.